# Managing Cookies from external backend-service

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, http, cookies

Let's say I've created a mobile application named 'Foo'(iOS). This app talks to a Java-running backend at 'java.com' and works perfectly. Now, I'm trying to create the website 'Foo.com' to let users enjoy the 'same' service on a browser/computer. So far, I've found that almost all calls needed to the API from the website can be done in JavaScript directly to the backend at 'java.com', including a login-function.

On the backend, I've implemented the standard 'doPost'-method to handle the login, and I create a Cookie to attach to the request.
The problem, I think, is that the users get the JavaScript from 'Foo.com', and the JavaScript tries to log in by using an AJAX-call to 'java.com', thus the cookie will be 'stamped' by www.java.com', not by 'www.foo.com', and the user will never receive the cookie. (At least, I don't receive a cookie now)

I've been trying to find a way to accept cookies from 'api.com' into the application, but it doesn't look good. Honestly, I'm not even sure this is the actual problem causing me to not receive a cookie, but I've read several places that cross-domain-cookies aren't allowed. So I ask the general question, how should I proceed?

I've been toying with the idea to add a .php-page to the server-side of the website 'foo.com', and from there handle the requests from client to API, hopefully causing the cookies to be 'stamped' as 'foo.com' instead of 'java.com'. (In that case, I'd also wonder if the .php can forward the information in the cookie or something similar).
But I really want to avoid as much traffic on the webhost as possible. An all-script-website would be optimal, but I don't really see how cookies can work with that.

Is there anything else I can do to handle this? If I simply want a persistent login-function from a client of 'foo.com' handled at 'java.com', are there any options, with or without the use of cookies?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies) would be helpful for you?